# How to use one common menu page in multiple pages using IONIC 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Using Ionic 4, I have created menu page and want to call this page inside multiple pages using ionic selector.

I have tried with exports in menu.module.ts as below.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [MenuPage],

  exports: [
    MenuPage
  ]
})
```

Can anyone please help me how can I do this and what changes should be required in module.ts file ?

Comment: What I understood is that you want to reuse your menu so you can use it in all the pages without having to rewrite a new menu on every page correct?

Comment: @PatricioVargas yes correct. I want to reuse menu page in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it would be the following:

**app.html**

```
 <ion-menu side="start">
   <ion-header translucent>
     <ion-toolbar color="secondary">
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

or you can create a child component and inject it to the app.html page. Whatever you put in the app.html layout will be in every single page of the app

I got the code from Ionic 4 website a: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/components/#menu

Whatever you put in app.html is what is going to be repetitive in every file.

Comment: The given link doesn't work anymore. This link be followed instead: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/tutorial/project-structure/

Comment: I am afraid this is not enough. I've created a menu as a component in my app, and I cannot put to work the <ion-menu-button> which is in every page....

Answer (score 0):

Add a menu button element under `<ion-toggle>` to all the pages wherever u want the menu slider like this:

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
 <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
</ion-buttons>
```